# Build error when replacing deprecated MagicalRecord methods in FTASync

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord, ftasync

I'm trying to get FTASync working for my iPad app.  This is the FTASync code that's giving me a build error and I don't know what's wrong with it.  I had to replace a deprecated statement:

```
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(localContext)
```

with the following (first statement; the remainder is original FTASync code)

```
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error){

    [self syncAll];
}

      completion:^{
          if (self.progressBlock)
              self.progressBlock(1.0, @"Complete");

          if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
              FSALog(@"%@", @"Completion block must be called on main thread");
          }

          //Use this notification and user defaults key to update an "Last Updated" message in the UI
          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"FTASyncLastSyncDate"];
          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FTASyncDidSync" object:nil];
          });

          if (completion)
              completion();

          self.syncInProgress = NO;
          self.progressBlock = nil;
          self.progress = 0;

          //End background task
          if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) {
              FSCLog(@"Completed sync.");
              [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
              bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
          }
      }];
```

This is the definition of **completion**:

> typedef void (^FTACompletionBlock)(void);

This is the build error I'm getting, which is probably caused by a syntax error somewhere, but I don't see it:

> No visible @interface for 'NSManagedObjectContext' declares the selector 'MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:completion:'

Can someone tell me what is causing this? and how to fix it?

Comment: How is `localContext` defined?  The compiler thinks it's a `NSManagedObjectContext` (which doesn't have a `MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion ` method).

Comment: This is the commentary from the .h file:

`/// \param       completion  Completion block that is called after the save has completed. The block is passed a success state as a `BOOL` and an `NSError` instance if an error occurs. Always called on the main queue.
/// \discussion Executes asynchronous saves on the current context, and any ancestors, until the changes have been persisted to the assigned persistent store. The completion block will always be called on the main queue.
- (void) MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:(MRSaveCompletionHandler)completion;`

Comment: I don't see how that says anything about the definition of `localContext`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by all of this.  In the MR 2.2 docs, it says this method exists; but when I preface the method call with **NSManagedOBjectContext** it gives me the error that the method doesn't exist.  Can you tell me what's going on with this mess?  (and maybe help me out of it?)

Comment: I don't know anything about MR really.  I was just responding to the fact that you're using a variable called `localContext` that apparently is a `NSManagedObjectContext` instead of whatever you thought it was.  What class is `MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion` a method in?

Comment: I am trying to sync Core Data on Parse.com.  There is an app (FTASync) that *supposedly* will do that.  However, it's riddled with useage of deprecated MagicalRecords methods, and is a nightmare to upgrade.  That said, I just found FTASync on Parse.com that has been modified for Parse.com specifically and it builds without any errors.  I'm giving up on the original version;  please re-write your comment as an answer so I can accept it, give you points and close it.  Thank you for your patience, I appreciate it.